# How to get mongodb sync or change log and apply it on another instance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoimport, mongoexport

Is it possible to get a changelog of changes in mongodb , say from a given timestamp and then apply it at another instance of mongodb?

These 2 instances have same collection but changes to one is independent of the other.

Ideally the change log would be a transaction log of all the data changes that have happened from a given instance of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the only way is to start the mongodb server in replica mode and get the oplog (as discussed with mongodb's solution architect - vigyan)

```
mongodb --replSet rs0
```

[link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) to convert your standalone server to replica